# Representation of all pass transfer functions/inner functions  as Blaschke product.

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control

What is the proof for: 'An all pass transfer function/inner function can be represented by a Blaschke Product' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atkinson, Discrete and continuous boundary problems, page 8.